# After Installing Ubuntu alongside Win 10, cant not boot into windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my Hp Envy Phoenix a couple of nights ago, it was getting late so I made sure I could use Ubuntu, logged in and then I shut it down, since I was tired. I tried selecting windows boot manager to boot windows 10 the following morning from  the Grub menu and I get an error message. I've tried trouble shooting, startup repair, refreshing, one message I received said that my hard drive is locked. My computer doesn't detect a recovery image or a restore point.

When installing Ubuntu, these are the steps I followed:
1.) created an empty partition in windows 10
2. downloaded a Ubuntu usb using the rufus flash drive creator
3. rebooted and used the install Ubuntu option.
4. I selected install alongside windows 10 for dual boot,
5. selected the city I am near and proceeded with the install

Windows 10 doesn't boot any more. Please help, I don't want to lose my data on the drives and am unable to access any files from Ubunutu, I reformatted all partitions in FAT, as opposed to ext4, NTFS, or EFI.

My system has both UIFE and BIOS, I've attached a video with all the start up options.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TahBUxBHr1U - this is the youtube video

Edit: here is the pastebin link to the Bootinfoscript results! http://paste.ubuntu.com/23167622/

Comment: All I want to do is be able to boot into windows! please help!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Please run the [Boot Info Script](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/). This will generate a file called `RESULTS.txt`. Post that file to [a pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and post the URL to your document here. This will give us more details about your configuration, which is required to base an answer on more than guesswork.

Comment: This has been a struggle to do even this simple task as I am this unfamiliar with Ubuntu, Here is the pastebin file: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23167622/

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration is rather confused:

- Your `/dev/sda` has a Windows boot loader in the first sector of the disk, as would be expected for a computer booting in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode; however, that disk uses the [GUID Partition Table (GPT),](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) which is not supported by any Windows BIOS-mode boot loader. This fact suggests you may have accidentally converted the disk from [Master Boot Record (MBR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) to GPT form. If so, you've rendered Windows unbootable. OTOH, maybe a Windows MBR boot sector got onto the disk in some other way -- say, by being placed there by some recovery tool that didn't know it was useless on that disk.
- Both `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb` are GPT disks with [EFI System Partitions (ESPs),](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) which hold EFI/UEFI-mode boot loaders. Neither of the ESPs seems to have the Windows EFI-mode boot loader, though (`bootmgfw.efi`). You might want to use Linux to manually look for a file by that name on either `/dev/sda2` or `/dev/sdb2`, just to confirm this diagnosis. If that file is missing and the computer had been booting Windows in EFI mode, then the fact that the file is missing explains the problem.
- Your `/dev/sda2` *does* hold an EFI-mode Linux boot loader, so Ubuntu is booting in EFI mode.
- Both `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sdb1` are identified as `Data partition (Windows/Linux)` and hold FAT filesystems. This is a bit unusual. In a standard Windows installation, `/dev/sda1` will be the ESP; however, manufacturers sometimes push the ESP up to `/dev/sda2` and devote `/dev/sda1` to a manufacturer-specific partition. This may use FAT, but it normally has a type code that would show up in the Boot Info Script output as something other than `Data partition (Windows/Linux)`. Your comment in your question that you "reformatted all partitions in FAT" may explain this oddity -- and perhaps more. If the manufacturer put the Windows boot loader on its own partition and you then wrote a fresh FAT to that partition, then you've wiped out your boot loader.
- Your `/dev/sdc` looks as if it holds FreeDOS, or perhaps Windows XP, depending on what bits of the Boot Info Script output you believe. Either way, `/dev/sdc` uses MBR. If it's bootable, it will be bootable only in BIOS mode, not in EFI mode. If you expect to switch between Ubuntu and whatever's on `/dev/sdc`, you'll need to use either my own [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) or the computer's built-in boot manager. The latter is adequate in many cases, but useless in others. (The quality of the built-in boot manager varies greatly from one computer to another.) OTOH, the boot loader information detected by Boot Repair might be leftover from an installation you're no longer using, in which case you can ignore this bullet point.

Overall, I'd say that you'll need to look to Windows tools and procedures to re-install a Windows boot loader. You may be able to adapt the procedure described in [this blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20170306032145/http://sdnalloh.com/converting-win7-from-mbr-to-gpt/) to get your system up and running; however, this is *not* a recipe-book solution! You'll mostly need to use steps from the second page of the blog -- "Copy Windows Boot Files" (on another computer with the *same* version of Windows that you're using) and "Setup the UEFI System Partition" and onward. Note that I've just skimmed this procedure, so I may be missing something important that might affect your installation. You'd probably do well to ask for help on a Windows forum -- or better yet, ask a local Windows guru friend to help you in person.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll let everyone know how it goes, I'll also try posting to Windows forums and see what they suggest

Answer (score 0):

Its been a while but I found the answer else where, It was the old wipe both drives, reformat and place the original drive back in its slot. Lost everything and had to fresh install windows, and haven't attempted it since. Maybe some other time...